# Unexpected map result in apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm working with apps script and have:

```
var json = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var objArray = JSON.parse(json) 
Logger.log(objArray);    
const indices = objArray.map(({ ' #':id }) => id);
Logger.log(indices);
```

Logger.log(objArray) gives:

```
[{ #=4626,  E=Yes,  Assd $=,  Eager=High,  New $=,  State=Louisiana,  Date=06/15/20,  County=St. Martin Parish}, { #=4623,  State=South Carolina,   E=Yes,  Acres=1.50,  Eager=Low,   Date=06/15/20,  New $=}, { County=Sedgwick County,  Eager=High,  Acres=0.13,  New $=,  E=No, #=4620,  Date=06/15/20,  State=Kansas}, ....
```

Logger.log(indices) gives:

```
[null, null, ....... null]
```

However the following:

```
const values = [
 { " #": "4596", " E": "Yes"},
 { " #": "4597", " E": "No"},
 { " #": "4598", " E": "Maybe"},
```

]

```
 const indices = values.map(({ " #" : id }) => id);

 console.log(indices);
```

when run in apps script produces:

```
[4596,4597,4598]
```

Why does the first not work ?

edit:

json:

```
 [{" #":"4626"," E":"Yes"," Date":"06/15/20"," County":"St. Martin Parish"," State":"Louisiana"," Acres":"15.00","  Eager":"High"},{" #":"4623"," E":"Yes"," Date":"06/15/20"," County":"Greenville County"," State":"South Carolina"," Acres":"1.50","Eager":"Low"},
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample value of `json` of `var json = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);` before `JSON.parse` is used?

Comment: Thank you for adding the information. Although it is my guess, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: I think that in your additional sample value, when `objArray` is `[{" #":"4626",,,},{" #":"4623",,,]`, `objArray.map(({ ' #':id }) => id);` returns `[4626,4623]`. So if the below modification was not the direct solution, as the next step, can you provide the sample value of `value` of `var value = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(json.getContentText()))`?

Comment: I think it's like this: `const indices=objA.map(obj=>obj[" #"]);`

Comment: If the space of key is different from the original value, namely, for example, when the key of `objArray` is `' #'` or `'#'` or `'# '`, how about testing `const indices = objArray.map(({' #': id1, '#': id2, '# ': id3}) => id1 || id2 || id3);`? Unfortunately, about this, I'm not sure whether this is directly related to your issue. I'm sorry.

Comment: `null` is probably due to empty objects at the end of array. You're probably not seeing everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this answer?

### Issue and workaround:

From the URL of your replying, I could understand about the reason of your issue. When the values are retrieved from the URL of `https://ssjbhokibi.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/hello/get`, I could confirm the values like your sample input values, and also confirm the same situation. When I checked the character, I could confirm that   of  `#` is not the space of `0020`, it's `00A0` which is the no-break space. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

And also, the value retrieved by `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)` is the object of Class HTTPResponse. So in this modification, `getContentText()` is used for retrieving the text value.

In order to remove your issue, how about the following modification?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your script is modified by replcing `0020` to `00A0`.

#### From:

```
var json = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var objArray = JSON.parse(json) 
const indices = objArray.map(({ ' #':id }) => id);
```

#### To:

```
var json = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var objArray = JSON.parse(json.getContentText());
const indices = objArray.map(({ ' #':id }) => id);
```

- **When I posted above modified script directly using `00A0` like `' #'`, it seems that `00A0` is automatically changed to `0020` by the render of Markdown. So in this case, when you directly see the source of my answer, you can see the modified script using `00A0`.**
- But in this case, I thought that the readability of the modified script might be low. So I would like to propose one more pattern as follows.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the key is created by converting `00A0` with `String.fromCharCode(160)`, and the value is retrieved.

#### From:

```
var json = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var objArray = JSON.parse(json) 
const indices = objArray.map(({ ' #':id }) => id);
```

#### To:

```
var json = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var objArray = JSON.parse(json.getContentText());
const indices = objArray.map(({[String.fromCharCode(160) + "#"]: id}) => id);
```

or

```
var json = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var objArray = JSON.parse(json.getContentText());
const indices = objArray.map(e => e[String.fromCharCode(160) + "#"]);
```

### Note:

- In your sample input value, `0020` is used for `#`. So I couldn't notice about this. But when I updated my answer using `00A0` like `' #'`, I noticed that `00A0` is automatically changed to `0020`. On the other hand, I could confirm that when the source is confirmed by clicking editing button, `' #'` uses `00A0`. And also, when I confirm your source of question, it can be confirm that the space of `[{" #":"4626",` uses `00A0`. When I tested this for rendering the Markdown, I noticed that it seems that when the render of Markdown is run, `00A0` is changed to `0020` even when that is written in the script. By this, I couldn't notice about the issue from your added sample input value. From this situation, I thought the same questions posted before might also have the same situation with this, and this might be the important point.

### References:

- [fetch(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String))
- [Class HTTPResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response)
- [String.fromCharCode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

Comment: I'm pretty sure HTTPResponse will automatically be converted to string on json.parse.  Furthermore, in logs after the parse, the keys=value format is present. `[{ #=4626,  E=Yes,  Assd $=,`. The error is possibly after the parse. But I might be wrong and let's see what op says.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for replying. Yes. I quite agree with you. So I proposed it as my guess. For example, if `const indices = objArray.map(({' #': id1, '#': id2, '# ': id3}) => id1 || id2 || id3);` is the same issue like `null`, I would like to propose to confirm `var json = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);` again.

Comment: I made the change to var objArray = JSON.parse(json.getContentText()); - This appears to have no effect .. url = https://ssjbhokibi.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/hello/get

Comment: @LDN Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your provided URL, I could confirm your issue and solution. By this, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @TheMaster From the URL providing by OP, I could know the reason of the issue and an important point. It was found that the issue was the space of `' #'` is `00A0` (the no-break space) which is not `0020` (the space). And, as an important point, it was found that when the Markdown source is rendered, `00A0` is automatically replaced with `0020`. So when the source is checked, it can confirm that `00A0` is used in the source. I thought that this is one of the reason of the delay understanding of the issue.

Comment: I ended up using pattern 2, first example.I'm now seeing ] [4636, 4629, 4627, 4626, 4623, 4620, 4618, 4616, 4615, 4614, 4613, 4612, 4611, 4609, 4607, 4605, 4596, 4593, 4588, 4583, 4581, 4579, 4578, 4576, 4575]. I don't understand how you were able to find out the space was 00A0  not 0020. How did you test this?

Comment: @LDN Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About the pattern 1, when the rendered Markdown is shown at the browser, `00A0` is replaced to `0020`. In this case, it is required to confirm the original source of Markdown. About your additional question, I could confirm the same situation with you by using your provided URL. So I confirmed the space with the binary editor. By this, I could know the reason of the issue.

Comment: @Tanaike Nice. I did have this suspicion and try to check the space. But the space here seemed normal(as explained by you)

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for replying. Yes. When the rendered result of Markdown is seen, it seems that `00A0` is automatically replaced with `0020`. By this, I couldn't notice about this soon. But, when you see the source of Markdown of the OP's question and my answer by clicking "edit" button, you can confirm that the space of `[{" #":"4626"` of OP's additional value and the pattern 1 of my answer is `00A0`. You can check `A0` by copy and paste to [this site](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-hex-bin-dec-converter.html). This is the new important information for me.

Comment: That's good to know. Thanks. I'd usually paste it in a Google sheets cell and check with `=CODE()`